# Two instances of one fragment class works incorrect

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created tabbed activity, which has viewpager with two instances of one fragment class. This fragment contains listbox, and I have written few functions to 
interact with listview items, and one function in activity to do the same thing. The point is when im trying to call fragment methods, it always trying to update the listview of fragment, which was created at first, but when i call function from activity it works absolutely correct. Whats the problem?

Here is the code of activity:

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();

    Toolbar toolbar;

    FloatingActionButton btnAddCategories;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

        assignElements();
        prepareToolbar();
        prepareEelements();

    }

    public void assignElements() {
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        btnAddCategories = findViewById(R.id.btnAddCategory);
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    }
    public void prepareToolbar() {
        toolbar.setTitle("Категории");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextLight));
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    public void prepareEelements() {
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        btnAddCategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TabCategoriesFragment tabCategoriesFragment = (TabCategoriesFragment) getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                tabCategoriesFragment.addNewCategory();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.homeAsUp:
                finish();
                break;
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = TabCategoriesFragment.newInstance(false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = TabCategoriesFragment.newInstance(true);
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

And of the fragment:

```
public class TabCategoriesFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_INCOMING = "Incoming";


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public int Incoming = -1;

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Categories> categories;
    CategoriesListViewAdapter categoriesListViewAdapter;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    public TabCategoriesFragment() {
    }
    public int selectedPostion;

    public static TabCategoriesFragment newInstance(boolean Incoming) {
        TabCategoriesFragment fragment = new TabCategoriesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean(ARG_INCOMING, Incoming);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            if (getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_INCOMING)) {
                Incoming = 1;
            } else {
                Incoming = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void assignElements(View view) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categoriesListViewAdapter = new CategoriesListViewAdapter(getContext(), categories);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public void prepareElements() {
        filldata();
        listView.setAdapter(categoriesListViewAdapter);
        categoriesListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedPostion = position;
                getActivity().openContextMenu(listView);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteCategory(boolean deletecosts, String name) {
        try {
            //delete from db
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Произошла ошибка" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        if (Incoming == 1) {
            return "incomingcategories";
        } else {
            return "outcomingcategories";
        }
    }

    public String getSign() {
        if (Incoming == 1) {
            return ">";
        } else {
            return "<";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_category_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //final int selectedPostion = ((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()).position;
        int id = item.getItemId();
        final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getContext());
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.categoryDelete:
                        deleteCategory(categories.get(selectedPosition);
                        filldata();
                        categoriesListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            case R.id.categorySetbydefault:
                        break;

           case R.id.categoriesSetBydefault:
          setCategoryBydefault(categories.get(selectedPostion).description);
                filldata();
                categoriesListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

        public void setCategoryBydefault(String name) {


   //set
        }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        prepareElements();
        CategoriesActivity categoriesActivity = (CategoriesActivity) getActivity();
    }

    public void filldata() {
        categories.clear();
        //do some stuff
    }

    public void addNewCategory() {
       //do some stuff
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_categories, container, false);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.CategoriesListView);
        assignElements(view);
        return view;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "it always trying to update the listview of fragment, which was created at first, but when i call function from activity it works absolutely correct". Which function are you referring to? How exactly does it not work as expected?

Comment: @MikeM. function which works absolutely well is onclcick listener of btnAddCategory, functions which works incorrect is every function which interacts with listview items in fragment like addCategory() or deleteCategory(), yes, i did not post code of them, but they do nothing except of db requests. As you can see, there is function filldata(), which gets data from db and puts to arraylist, and it called everytime when db changed.

Comment: Well, don't see where you're calling `addNewCategory()` in the `Fragment` class, and the `deleteCategory()` call you do have there won't even compile. How are you determining that "it always trying to update the listview of fragment, which was created at first"? Do you mean that, if you're in the second `Fragment`, and you `addNewCategory()`, it does not show there? But if you go back to the first, it does show in that one?

Comment: @MikeM. By pressing on listview item you can call context menu, which has item "categoryDelete", when you click on it, it must to delete category from database and then update listview. This item works fine when youre on the first tab, it deletes category from db and refill listview, but when youre trying to delete category from context menu from second tab, it anyway deletes category from first tab and update listview from it, and keep second tab's listview unchanged

Comment: Yeesh, that was a fun one. OK, your problem is the context menu. When an item is selected, the `onContextItemSelected()` method is called for every active `Fragment` until one of them returns true to indicate that it has handled the click.  Since you're not somehow checking if the context menu belongs to the current `Fragment`, your first one just always processes it, and returns true. That's why it only ever affects the first list. We need to somehow differentiate which `ListView` the menu is meant for.

Comment: The first solution I came up with is grabbing the menu info's `targetView`, getting its parent, and then checking if it's the `ListView` in the current `Fragment`. If so, process the selection, and return true. Otherwise, return the `super` method's return. That is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IhY9ImLxpkfxPORl-f2B6X7XU6oSXtNq/view?usp=drivesdk. You should also remove the `listView.setOnItemLongClickListener()` call, as it's redundant with the `registerForContextMenu()`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay, your solution works perfectly, thank you very much, you are truly wizard. I'm glad you found my question was funny, I hope he delivered you at least a drop of fun) Thank you!)